# Why does IEnumerable's Where pass first argument as "this"

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, linq

I've just started to study on LINQ. The following example uses `Where` which is one of the *standard query operators*.

```cs
string[] names = { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry" };
IEnumerable<string> filteredNames = System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(names, n => n.Length >= 4);
```

I did some research on how it works and found [this source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs):

```cs
public static partial class Enumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
        if (source is Iterator<TSource>) return ((Iterator<TSource>)source).Where(predicate);
        if (source is TSource[]) return new WhereArrayIterator<TSource>((TSource[])source, predicate);
        if (source is List<TSource>) return new WhereListIterator<TSource>((List<TSource>)source, predicate);
        return new WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>(source, predicate);
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

I don't understand why its first parameter, `this IEnumerable<TSource> source`, is prefixed with the `this` keyword. I know that extension methods allow an existing type to be extended with new methods without
altering the definition of the original type and that the type
of the first parameter will be the type that is extended.

Can you explain its logic beneath?

Comment: Are you asking *why* the C# language requires you to write `this` to define an extension method?

Comment: Implementation of non-static methods is such that there is a hidden parameter to every method call. So every non-static method can be imagined as a static one, with one additional parameter: `this`. So, it makes sense to declare one parameter as `this` in extension methods. It's a perfect keyword for it.

Comment: Well, there needs to be some way for the compiler to interpret this fuction as extension-method. This is done by that syntax. Why it is `this` and not e.g. `default`? How should anyone know?

Comment: @CorentinPane no.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it is an [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

So that instead of

```
IEnumerable<string> filteredNames = System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(names, n => n.Length >= 4);
```

You can also use it like:

```
IEnumerable<string> filteredNames = names.Where(n => n.Length >= 4);
```

The Reason it is an extension method is that IEnumerable, List, ... existed long before Linq (which was introduced in .Net 3.5) and its job is just to extend finding, filtering, ordering, ... them. So it is logical to have it as an Extention method rather than a separate library. And also consider that this way you can use chaining, which woudln'd be possible if it wasn't an extension:

```
name.Where(x => x.Length > 4).Select(x => x.Substring(4));
```

Compare it to:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(name, x => x.Length > 4), x => x.Substring(4));
```

And this is only a very simple one, consider how dirty it gets with larger, complex queries.

Comment: if it wasn't extension, that is if it is normally involved in at the design times of `IEnumerable`, still is chaining not possible? For example by returning `this`?

Comment: No. because as in my example for chaining it had to be used as argument of another method `Sum(Where(Select(....)))`

Comment: but if it returns `this`, it can be called as ...Sum.Where.Select ?? I cannot grasp its logic. Could you more exemplify?

Comment: well, if Where,Select,... are Extension Methos, otherwise, although the returned type is an IEnumerable (as you are returning it) but it won't have these methods available.

Comment: but what about if I have, just assume?

Comment: @snr lets chat (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204198/ashkan)[https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204198/ashkan]

Answer (score 2):

Since it's an Extension Method. It means that Where is not a method on IEnumerable but when you reference Linq namespace ,Where method is added to IEnumerable.

for more info read this :
[Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, The simple answer is because it is an extension method. The definition of extension method is that Their first parameter specifies which type the method operates on, and the parameter is preceded by the **this** modifier. 
Secondly, I disagree Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani's answers last part. you must have a look fluent implementation without extension method.